# How to keep class and private instance variables in proguard

Tags: android, proguard

Hi I am using proguard in my android application and I am using one class with some instance variables and I don't want proguard to change those instance variables.

Here is my class:

```
public class Repository  {
   
    private Set<String> mInstalledApps;
}
```

I don't want proguard to change mInstalledApps.

Here are the commands which I have tried but not working:

```
-keep class .Repository
-keepclassmembers class .Repository
-keepnames class .Repository

-keepclassmembers public class .Repository {
    *;
}

-keep public class .Repository$* {
        *;
 }
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard requires you to provide the full class path in your -keep rule, you can preserve all private fields of a class as shown below;

```
-keep class com.example.Repository {
    private <fields>;
}
```

In case you just wish to keep the `mInstalledApps` field, you can use a -keep option as shown below;

```
-keep class com.example.Repository {
    java.util.Set mInstalledApps;
}
```

You can play around with your -keep rules using the [ProGuard PlayGround](https://playground.proguard.com/), that way you do not need to compile your project over and over again to see their effect.